# Cannot solve: PHP Warning: POST Content-Length of 13110857 bytes exceeds the limit of 10485760 bytes in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, post, upload, size, content-length

I try to modify the `post_max_size`, `upload_max_filesize` and `memory_limit` I just cannot avoid this:

> PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 13110857 bytes exceeds the limit
>   of 10485760 bytes in Unknown on line 0

I dont know where `10485760` comes from, I'm using JustHost service and Choosing Single 'php.in', php5.4

Comment: 10485760 bytes = 10MB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If You work on local after change all settings in php.ini restart appache, if you work on server and have access with ssh you can implement same things and change post_max_size (if server give access to do that), or contact with support and than change size.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting that error, it means the `post_max_size` edit you attempted failed.

Contact your host for a bigger limit.

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini file setting

find post_max_size and set the desire value.